# Deploying an iOS App using PhoneGap From Windows

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am new to PhoneGap and Mobile Application Development. I want to create an application using PhoneGap so that I can get Android, iOS, BlackBerry versions of the same app.

I have installed PhoneGap in my windows 7 Desktop using tutorials given in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqFpfrUrMM4

I have some questions regrading PhoneGap:

1. Can we create multiple pages(HTML Files) or we only have index.html single file?
2. Can we use jQuery UI plugins, Mobile jQuery UI and other iQuery plugins? Will PhoneGap cloud service be able to convert to mobile app?
3. I have created Hello World example and uploaded zip file to PhoneGap and it converted to Android, Windows app but for iOS app it shows error certificate(P12) and provisioning file. I have windows 7, how can I get that legally? (My friend has Mac book. I can use it)
4. I want to launch app to Play market and iTunes but I have no idea what I need to do after uploading zip to phonegap.

I will really appreciate if you can provide me with the suggestions, steps that I need to take or links that would ease whole process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can make multi-page apps with PG. All of my apps are.
2. You can use those plugins. If they work on a regular web site, they'll work in PhoneGap. PhoneGap Build should be able to package all the scripts as one app, as long as the content is within their guidelines.
3. You need a Mac to get it. This page gives a lot of directions: http://centuryware.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/how-to-create-and-test-ios-apps-on-phonegap-build/
4. You'll need to sign up for a Developer account at https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action to upload an app there, and a Google Play account at http://developer.android.com/index.html to upload to that store. Once you sign up, read their docs. It can get pretty involved on the Apple side.

Comment: Thanks Steve! Guidelines that you have provided is very useful to me.